# Crontab 'No MTA installed, discarding output'

Tags: python, cron

Crontab does not write into the specified logfile. Is there any syntax error in my command?

```
*/5 * * * * (cd /some/dir && python -m some.python.module)  >> /dir/with/the/logfile.log 2>&1
```

I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog) as reference where

```
0 3 * * * (cmd1;  cmd2)  >> /some/log/file 2>&1
```

is suggested. When I execute the two commands by hand they work perfectly fine and I can see the output on `stdout`.

Comment: Does it have write permission to /dir/with/the/logfile.log
What does syslog show in that time?